# Japanese honourifics during the Heian period

Tags: classical-japanese, honorifics, archaic-language

I'm just curious about honorifics during the Heian period. I know that "daredare no kimi" was used often in court however I am curious about other honorifics extant during the period. Particularly I want to know what the period equivalent of "onushi sama" would be.

Comment: Can I assume you're only interested in "the respectful version of *thy* in Japanese"? It requires an entire book chapcter to even explain the basics of "honorifics during the Heian period".

Comment: Specifically, I wish to refer to a person of around the 5th/6th rank in court without referring to them by name from the position of a commoner sort of like "お主様"

Comment: oh, I should mention the person being addressed is male and the first particle in the sentence would be の, if you do have a chapter on honorifics of middle Japanese lying around I'd love to read it.

Comment: So you are looking for 2nd person pronouns in conversation? [This](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kotoba/42/0/42_54/_pdf/-char/ja) may be of interest  (p58)  thought it is letters. [This](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10180719460) says mostly it is unknown how people call each other in the era, but high class people were using just full names.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful.